# Mudblazor - Styling Components: e.g:Table

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

How is the correct way to apply styiling to a MudBlzaor component, in specific, to a table?:

**Code**

```
<MudTable>
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh> Some Random Header</MudTh>
        ...
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd> Some Random Content</MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
</MudTable>
```

**Questions**

1: Can I apply a style in any way it will apply to all elements inside the component, in this example apply a style to `<HeaderContent>` and all `<MudTh>` would have it.

2: How to use the Class property? I have use it in `<MudTh>` but it doesn't work (I can't even find it in inspect mode, it is applied to the element but it won't appear in the styles section).

**PS:** I can apply inline Style to the elements, but that doesn´t seem neither feasible nor scalable.

**EDIT**

**taskDetails.razor**

```
<MudTable>
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh Class="tableHeader"><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<TaskItemDisplayModel, object>(x => x.Name)"></MudTableSortLabel>Name</MudTh>
        @*<MudTh Style="font-weight:bold;"><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<TaskItemDisplayModel, object>(x => x.Name)"></MudTableSortLabel>Name</MudTh> THIS WORKS*@
```

**taskDetails.razor.css**

```
...
.tableHeader {
    font-weight:bold;
}
...
```

[image]

**Note**
I can use classes on other non-MudBlazor elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your probably looking for CSS Isolation - see [MS Docs - Css Isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

You should also be able to set the class directly on the component like this (assuming MudBlazor allows it):

```
<MudTd class="table-row"> Some Random Content</MudTd>
```

If your using component Css and it's on the parent component, then you'll need to apply the `deep` attribute to the Css class for the child components to be able to use it.

```
::deep td.table-row { 
    color: red;
}
```

##### Update based on new Info in Question

If your component Css was correctly configured you should see something like this

```
<table b-2rnu6n50b3 class="mud-table-root">
....
</table>
```

As there's no Id on `<table>` then maybe MudBlazor doesn't handle the ID'ing. Try adding a containing `div` to *TableDetails.razor*

```
<div>
<MudTable>
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh Class="tableHeader"><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<TaskItemDisplayModel, object>(x => x.Name)"></MudTableSortLabel>Name</MudTh>
......
</div>
```

Then check that the `div` gets the correct ID.

You can see the css files and the IDs in the *obj* hidden folder:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I'm using a scoped CSS file. MudBlazor allows you to do this: `<MudTd Class=""> Some Random Content</MudTd>` (class with uppercase). But even though I have the class on the .razor.css the styles won't apply. (it still appears referenced on the element, but not on the styles section of the inspect mode)

Comment: Check that you have the project stylesheet referenced in your startup html page, and you can see the styles you are using in the stylesheet.  Also do a full project build to make sure the Css IDs match.

Comment: Yes it is referenced. I am using it for some natural elements and it works with no problems. I believe the problem is related to MudBlazor.

Comment: Check my update answer on `deep`.  Can you show a section of the html and the corresponding styles from the stylesheet (in the browser) in your question?

Comment: Tried the deep bit and it didn't work, in visual studio says deep is not a valid pseudo-element, do I need a package or something? Will update my answer in a bit to show what you asked for.

Comment: See added info in the answer.  You do need the ::deep - ignore the warning.

Comment: I tried surrouding the `MudTable` as you suggested. It gets the component ID and the .css in obj folder is correct. It seems the problem is indeed MudBlazor not handling the ID's which seems strange since MudBlazor is designed for Blazor (duh :D). Will dig some more and if I found out that is indeed the case will mark this as an answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Seems like this was a pretty basic css mistake. It appears you have to put `!important` when styling a table header (but the `::deep` was needed anyways). Sorry for the inconvenience.